# Translate values for SI_SCHEDULE_STATUS in XI query builder

Tags: c#, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I'm getting started with the Business Objects SDK and I'm having trouble finding a reference for the numerical values for the SI_SCHEDULE_STATUS property.  I've seen example queries on the web for things like:

```
SELECT SI_NAME FROM CI_INFOOBJECTS WHERE SI_RECURRING = 1 and SI_SCHEDULE_STATUS = 9
```

But what is SI_SCHEDULE_STATUS 9?  What are the other possible values?  I found [this](http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxir2/en/en/boe_sdk/boesdk_dotnet_doc/doc/boesdk_net_doc/html/QueryLanguageReference150.html#2301823) which mentions that the values are mapped to an enumeration, but I'm not sure how (or if) I can translate this to the numeric value expected by the Query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more search and I found an answer [here](http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?p=799366&sid=e2e7321f72d1dc78c1105196a236f961).

```
COMPLETE 1 
FAILURE  3 
PAUSED   8 
PENDING  9 
RUNNING  0
```